# Javascript - How to add 0 to 10 options to select element?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to understand to why my code only creates this single option:

[image]

And not options from 0 to 10?

```html
<div>
  <div id="SelectEl">

  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // Get el ID
  var el = document.getElementById('SelectEl');
  // Select element
  var selectList = document.createElement('select');
  // Option element
  var option = document.createElement('option');


  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    // Add selectList element to div
    el.appendChild(selectList);
    // Add option to selectList
    selectList.appendChild(option);
    // Add text of a number 0 to 10
    option.text = [i]
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Because you only have one option, and you are appending it over and over and over.  It's not going to clone it automatically.  It just moves it.  You need to create your option variable inside the loop

Comment: It's also a code smell that you are appending the select over and over.

Comment: @Taplar ahh - Right, If I were to move the `var option` within the loop, that would create me multiple `options`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div>
    <div id="SelectEl">

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Get el ID
    var el = document.getElementById('SelectEl');
    // Select element
    var selectList = document.createElement('select');
    // Option element
    var option;


    for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        option = document.createElement('option');
        
        // Add text of a number 0 to 10
        option.text = [i]
        // Add option to selectList
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }

    // Add selectList element to div
    el.appendChild(selectList);

</script>
```

- Create a new option each iteration.
- Append the whole select after the loop.

Comment: That makes alot of sense now - learned a very useful lesson today! Appreciate that! Amazed what you can do with JavaScript now :D

Answer (score 1):

Create the option element inside the loop, one for each iteration, and move the line where you append the selectList to the div to outside the loop:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('SelectEl');
const selectList = document.createElement('select');
el.appendChild(selectList);

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  selectList.appendChild(option);
  option.text = [i]
}
```

```html
<div id="SelectEl"></div>
```